# How to count "active" cases using bupaR?

Tags: r, bupar

I'd like to count the number of patients simultaneaously present in the hospital, using **bupaR**.
For this problem, I'll be using the **patients** eventlog.

One can calculate a throughput time for the whole process

```
library(bupaverse)
library(tidyverse)

patients %>% throughput_time(level = "log")
```

But is it possible to count the number of cases simultaneously present for the whole expected trace (from start of  Registration to end of Chek-out) or during one or a group of activities ?

I think I can do something similar using the data.table package :

```
library(data.table)
df = patients %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  summarise(In = time[handling == "Registration" & registration_type == "start"],
            Out = time[handling == "Check-out" & registration_type == "complete"]
  ) %>%
  as.data.table  %>%
  setkey(In, Out)


DatesList <- tibble(In = seq.Date( min(patients$time) %>% as_date(),
                                   max(patients$time) %>% as_date(), by= "day"), 
                    Out = In + days(1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.POSIXct(.x, , tz = "UTC"))) %>%
  setDT()


patients.present = foverlaps(DatesList, df, type="any") %>%
  .[, .(N = .N), by = "i.In"] 

stats.patients.present = patients.present$N %>% summary
stats.patients.present

patients.median = stats.patients.present %>% .[3]

patients.present %>% 
  ggplot(aes(i.In, N)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = patients.median, color = "red")
```

Can someone tell me if the bupaverse is able to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot for your help !